# How do you increase the horsepower of an electric motor?

Tags: motors, automotive-engineering, battery, electric-vehicles

I read that a Tesla Model S P100D achieved 730 horsepower on a dynamometer. Would increasing battery size increase the horsepower? If not, what would?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A Tesla battery is made from many cells, there is a max current rating for each cell, a larger battery has more cells and therefore give out a larger peak current. (Ian ringrose)

It is also linked to the naximum output of the electric motor. Which produces the rotation.

Comment: This does not answer the question. There is a maximum output of the electric motor. We do not know if the current battery pack can or cannot supply the current to achieve this.

Comment: I have edited it, @Drew_J

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the battery size would increase the range of the vehicle, not the horsepower.
Increasing the mechanical output of the motor would increase horsepower, but reduce range.

Comment: But there have been improvements in performance with increased battery size. On a dynomometer a p100d has more horsepower than p90d when all that is different is battery pack, @user11068

Comment: A Tesla battery is made from many cells, there is a max current rating for each cell, a larger battery has more cells and therefore give out a larger peak current.

Comment: @SRawes That would be a great piece of info to cite in your answer.